# How to set the duration of a "loading spinner", based on the loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made a loading "animation.gif" for my dynamic website. This is the code I used from jquery, to show and hide the spinner:

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $(this).show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

---

**My Problem:**
The website has different contents (like flash, images, text etc.). So some parts of the website take longer to load then others. But the duration of loading animation is always the same(its too fast). When I load a content with a flash(4mb) and html text, the spinner hides way too fast, and the content is still loading. The same with HQ images..

I could use a min delay, like:

```
$("#this").delay(600).fadeOut("slow");
```

But I dont think this is a good solution at all.
***How is it possible not to hide the loading-spinner, until the whole content is loaded?***

Comment: do you know which elements are loading slower, and how many there are, are you in control of the page?

Comment: you should bind the .hide() event to something like .load() in your body/img/flash stuff

Comment: @AMember <object>(flash) and 
<img>, and yes I am in control.

Comment: @Onheiron makes sense, how would the code look like? (unfortunately I'm just a poor designer) :(

Comment: have added another possible solution... not great but might work.

Answer (score 1):

What you can is create a list of flags for all of the slow loading elements in your page.

Then start listening to each of the elements load event ( You can do it with flash as well ).

Each time an element is loaded raise its flag.

Have a interval run in the background that watch this list, once all of list items are raised, remove the loading-spinner.

You can also try this:

```
var iv = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.all["theObject"].readyState == 4) {
        clearInterval(iv)
        alert("Object loaded (maybe).")
    }
}, 100)
```

taken from : http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?160792-lt-object-onload,

by Orc Scorcher

Comment: this answer is kinda good, but I'd remove that interval loop and just check if the list is complete each time an element is done loading.

Comment: Thank you, but I didnt get an alert wenn I tested this one. Is there o working example? Maybe I am doing it wrong.

This works for example (only with images):
  

`$("#image_ID").load(function() {
 alert("Object loaded (maybe).")
});`

Answer (score 0):

From the very page you linked to, just bind to `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` instead, which have the required logic built-in and only fire for the first AJAX request in any group, and when the last AJAX request completes.

Alternatively, you can use your own counter to figure out how many AJAX requests are outstanding:

```
(function(sel) {
    var count = 0;

    $(sel).bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        if (count++ === 0) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    }).bind("ajaxComplete", function() {
        if (--count === 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
})('#loading');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried out [this one (Fiddle Here)](http://jsfiddle.net/nuYpH/2/) and hope is what you're looking for.

Basically:

- give each element you want the loader to wait for a `.content` class
- dynamically set content src with your jQuery/AJAX whatever
- bind `$('.content')` elements to a `.load()` event
- when `.load()` is fired increment a counter, if the counter equals the `.length` of `$('.content')` selector then hide the loading gif

From [jQuery Site](http://api.jquery.com) about [.load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) :

> This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

So it should work fine with your lazy content.

Hope it helps!